# How do i login with registrations table in cakephp 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

i m newbie for cakephp and i want to log in with different MySQL table name "registrations". as according to cakephp book a users  named table is needed to log in and registration and its User controller and model. but my question is. is there any way to login with registrations table ? Here i difine you what all pages for it.

**Controller**
AppController.php
OnlineController.php(this page is main controller for my site.)

**Model**
AppModel.php
Registrations.php

**View**
register.ctp
login.ctp

And here my login view page

```
<?php echo  $this->Form->create('Registrations'); ?>
<table width="450" border="0" align="center" id="login_form">
  <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="2" align="left"><h3 style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:0px;">Login In</h3>
    <hr /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><?php  echo $this->Session->flash(); ?></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="245"><?php echo $this->Form->input('email'); ?></td>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password')); ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><a href="#">Lost Username/Password</a></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><? echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); ?></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And Controller >> OnlineController.php >> Code here

class OnlineController extends AppController {

```
/**
 * Controller name
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $name = 'Online';
    //component
    public $components=array('Session','Paginator','Auth');


    public $uses = array('Registrations','Contacts','User','RegistrationsModel');

function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
}

    public function index(){
        //$students=$this->Student->find('all');


    }

public function login(){
if($this->request->is('post'))
    {

// pr($_POST);

 if ($this->Auth->login()) {

          return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());


            // Prior to 2.3 use `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        } 

        else {

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }


    }
      }

    public function logout() {
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
    public function profile()
    {

    }
```

Model Part>> Registrations.php and code is

```
class Registrations extends AppModel {


 public  $name='Registrations';


function beforeSave() {
  if(isset($this->data['Registrations']['password']))
    $this->data['Registrations']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['Registrations']['password'], null, true);
  return true;
}
public $validate = array(
                     'first_name'=>array(
                  'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                  'required'=> true,
                  'allowEmpty'=>false,
                  'message'=>'Please Enter Your Name'
                  ),
                  'last_name'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your Last Name."


                  ),

                  'email'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'email',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your Email address."


                  )
                   ,


                    'password'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your Password."


                  ),
                      'phone'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'Numeric',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your Phone No.."


                  )



                  ,
                      'state'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your Sate"


                  )

                    ,
                      'city'=>array(

                   'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                   'required'=>true,
                   'allowEmpty'=>false,
                   'message'=>"Please Enter Your City"


                  )


);
```

}

In last i useed some logic for Appcontroller

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'Online',
            'action' => 'login'),

            'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Online',
            'action' => 'profile'),

                'logoutRedirect ' => array(
            'controller' => 'Online',
            'action' => 'login'),

        'authenticate' => array(
         'Registrations' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'RegistrationsModel',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
        )
    )
    )
);



   function beforeFilter() {
       $this->Auth->allow('register','index','contact','quiz_zone','about','packages','online_test','test_gen','login');



      } 
}
```

Please give me a correct solution..Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The name of the table for login is irrelevant. CakePHP doesn't empose a name for that.
This is a setting. When configuring your `AuthComponent` in AppController for example do:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Registration'));
```

In your example you're passing the wrong name: `RegistrationsModel`.

So in your example this is very WRONG:

```
 'authenticate' => array(
         'Registrations' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'RegistrationsModel',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
        )
```

The first level key should be the [authentication type](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) (Form, Basic, Digest) not `Registrations`. Then as I explained you can do:

```
 'authenticate' => array(
         'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Registration',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
        )
```

This is all very well explained in the book - [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).

Another very bad thing that you're NOT DOING is [following the CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html)!
Cake follows the philosophy of "Convention over configuration".
For example your models should be singular not plural... Read the book. Start with the turotioals.